# I need to remove with bash two characters from one long line xml string

Tags: macos, bash

I'm reading from stdin line by line strings like:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">\n<Datanode ....
```

I need to get rid of that `\n` , it is not a newline, just a nasty sequence.
I need to read it form pipe, process it and pipe further.
Usually I got help from tr or cut but against this sequence I cannot find the way, they either do not remove it, or remove some other "n"s from XML string as well.

Comment: Definitely not recommended to parse structured languages like HTML or XML using `bash`, `grep`, `sed`, `cut`, etc. Look into `xmllint`, `xmlstarlet`, `xpath`, `xsltproc`, ... Eg. `xmllint --xpath '//person[@name="bob"]/salary/text()' 
                - <<< '<staff><person name="bob"><salary>70000</salary></person></staff>'`

Comment: Fixing the code that generated that invalid XML (with a text node outside the root) would be the ideal approach.

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein, I agree with you in general, but is the content in question *actually valid XML* with text outside the root node? If not, these tools won't be able to process it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Well, I agree with you too :-)

Comment: BTW -- just removing the `\n` isn't enough either: You need to change it from `<xml ...>` to `<?xml ...?>` to make it a valid header.

Comment: ...that said, if the code you're getting your input from can't even get the header right, I'm not sure whether your body content will be valid XML either -- there are lots of corner cases (element escaping and such), and it's obviously not using a tested and compliant generation library.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to remove the string made of '\' followed by 'n' ok?

Something like this should work:

```
... | sed 's/\\n//' | ...
```

or this if you want to remove multiple sequences:

```
... | sed 's/\\n//g' | ...
```

And, if you want to anchor the sequence to be removed:

```
... | sed 's/>\\n</></' | ...
```

**UPDATE**

In case you don't want to *remove* the sequence '\''n' but *replace* it with a real new line (and I did notice your tag **osx**), you might want to use the following:

```
... | sed -e 's/\\n/\'$'\n/' | ...
```

Comment: It looks to me like he wants to turn `\\n` into `\n` as it looks like there should be a newline there (for cosmetic purposes only, of course).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy he can use the anchor version (and possibly "increase" the anchor size)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that your document isn't valid XML on account of containing a text node outside the root, which would explain why you can't use conventional XML-centric tools.

To *truly* use only bash, and do this in a manner that's safe against corrupting your file (performs the replacement *only* for the exact header text *only* on the very first line):

```
correct_xml_header() {
  local bad_header correct_header content
  bad_header='<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">\n'
  correct_header='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
  IFS= read -r -d '' content
  if [[ $content = "$bad_header"* ]]; then
    content=${correct_header}${content#"$bad_header"}
  fi
  printf '%s' "$content"
}
```

You can then pipe through this function:

```
generate_bad_xml | correct_xml_header | consume_good_xml
```

If you want to add a literal newline, add `$'\n'` to the end of the definition of `correct_header`, as in:

```
correct_header='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'$'\n'
```

---

Note that I'm also changing `<xml ...>` to `<?xml ...?>`, which is a change similarly necessary to make this tool's output parse correctly with XML-compliant tools.

Comment: OP requests was "...I need to read it form pipe, process it and pipe further..."

Comment: @mauro, then it's easy to write to stdout and read from stdin by just taking out the redirections.